# Como remover linha em branco "Return"

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Eu tenho um `TextBox` onde o usuário vai digitar.

Não posso deixar nenhuma linha em branco (return "\r") antes de enviar para o banco de dados. No meu código, funciona bem quando encontra `\r\r`, mas não quando têm `\r\r\r`

Como posso resolver isso?

O texto deve ficar assim:

```
exemplo
exemplo
exemplo
```

Não assim:

```
exemplo


exemplo

exemplo
exemplo
```

Código:

```
     while (insObs.Text != "")
     {
         if (insObs.Text.Contains("\r\r"))
         {
            vaiObs = insObs.Text.Replace("\r\r", "\r");
             break;
         }

     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está executando o loop apenas uma vez, assim ele substitui apenas as ocorrências diretas de `\r\r`, porém ao remover um dos returns o que sobra concatena com o próximo.

Mude seu trecho de código para:

```
vaiObs = insObs.Text;
while (vaiObs.Text.Contains("\r\r"))
{
    vaiObs = vaiObs.Text.Replace("\r\r", "\r");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa alternativa seria você usar regex! Veja:

```
            using System;
        using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
        namespace teste
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {

                    string[] itens = { "exemplo1", "\r", "exemplo3", "exemplo4", "\r", "\r\r\r\r", "exemplo7", "exemplo8" };
                    Regex r = new Regex(@"\r",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    foreach (string e in itens)
                        if(!r.IsMatch(e))
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Veja funcionando na prática:

http://ideone.com/8zo4Nh

Referência:
 [System.Text.RegularExpressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Método Regex.Match (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)